# Xamarin iOS : Filtering out the FileType show on Document Picker

Tags: ios, xamarin, file-type, contenttype

I am trying to filter out all the files which is not image, video, audio, pdf and other document files e.g. microsoft.

At the moment, I have this in my code:

```
var allowedUTIs = new string[] {
            UTType.Image,
            UTType.PDF,
            UTType.Video,
            UTType.Audio,
            UTType.Movie,
            UTTYPE.Text,
            "com.microsoft.word.doc",
            "com.microsoft.excel.xls",
            "com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt",
            "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"
        };
```

Main concern are the type custom defined. Does it cover all the microsoft offices file type: doc, xls, ppt, docx etc...

Is there any other document type I have not covered e.g. apple's specific document file.

Comment: How do you find out these definitions? For example, what about xml or xsl files?

Answer (score 5):

```
        var allowedUtis = new string[] {
            UTType.UTF8PlainText,
            UTType.PlainText,
            UTType.RTF,
            UTType.PNG,
            UTType.Text,
            UTType.PDF,
            UTType.Image,
            UTType.UTF16PlainText,
            UTType.FileURL,
            "com.microsoft.word.doc",
            "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document",
            "com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt"
            "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation",
            "com.microsoft.excel.xls"
        };
```

These are my UTTypes,

In this, for doc "com.microsoft.word.doc", for docx "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document" and so on. I've tested against all the documents.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use like this

```
       var fileTypes = new string[] {
        "public.utf8-plain-text", 
        "public.plain-text", 
        "public.text",
        "public.png", 
        "public.jpeg", 
        "com.microsoft.bmp",           
        "public.composite-content" 
        "com.adobe.pdf",
        "public.image", 
        "public.file-url", 
        "com.microsoft.word.doc",
        "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document",
        "com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt",
        "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation",
        "com.microsoft.excel.xls"
         };
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

EDIT

Using Xamarin essentials

```
    var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
   {
     {              
      DevicePlatform.Android, fileTypes
     },
     {
        DevicePlatform.iOS, fileTypes
     }
   });
       

 var file = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
 {
    PickerTitle = "Please select a file",
    FileTypes = customFileType,
 });
```

Comment: What about XSL and XMl files? And, how do we use these with Xamarin.Essential FilePicker?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Refer the link for extensions in the answer and I added code for file picker for xamarinessential

Comment: Thanks. In the end I also had to add entries into my Info.plist to register my custom file types too (like CSS) else the iPad / iPhone would not let you select these types of files.

Answer (score 2):

To allow video, and audio files there is an options too, if not added it will show that files but disabled you can not pick that.

```
var allowedUTIs = new string[]
{
    UTType.UTF8PlainText,
    UTType.PlainText,
    UTType.RTF,
    UTType.PNG,
    UTType.Text,
    UTType.PDF,
    UTType.Image,
    UTType.UTF16PlainText,
    UTType.FileURL,
    UTType.Spreadsheet,
    UTType.MP3,
    UTType.MPEG4,
    UTType.MPEG4Audio,
    UTType.WaveformAudio,
    UTType.Audio,
    UTType.Video,
    UTType.GIF,
    UTType.BMP,
    "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document",
    "com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt",
    "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation",
    "com.microsoft.excel.xls",
    "com.microsoft.waveform-​audio",
    "com.microsoft.windows-​media-wmv",
    "com.adobe.illustrator.ai-​image"
};
```

Apple document: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html